# Unexpected pause in video after concatenating multiple mp4 files using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

I am trying to concatenate more than 90 small MP4 videos for a single MP4 file.
i got code reference from [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#extscript)
, i successfully got an output.mp4 file, but i tried to play video, there is a long pause between videos, searched and got this [here is the link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#extscript), but failed.

```
CMD CODE: ffmpeg -y -f concat -i inputs.txt -c copy output.mp4

inputs.txt is like

file video_1.mp4
duration 17
file video_2.mp4
duration 25
file video_3.mp4
duration 45
file video_4.mp4
duration 15
file video_5.mp4
duration 10
file video_6.mp4
duration 20
file video_7.mp4
duration 25
file video_8.mp4
duration 20
file video_9.mp4
duration 15
file video_10.mp4
duration 12
```

Please help me.

Comment: any chance of sharing the python code you used with us? we will like to see how you called the files etc and the library names.

Comment: Question has been edited, actually i am using CLI to concatenate videos. lib is ffmpeg

Comment: ffmpeg default setting can add pauses because of mismatches, but you can check that resolution, frames rates and timebase match and amend accordingly

Comment: Remove the duration directives. Not needed when joining containers like mp4.

Comment: i have already checked by removing duration directives but problem is till same.
Moviepy is working fine but its taking too much time and memory causing system slow.

Comment: having the same issue.. tried different stuff like aresample, etc